# JavaScript doesn't work in production enviroment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I'm using datatables, a plugin in JavaScript to sort, filter, search... of records in a table.

Searching in some foruns, I saw if I set this line below in config/enviroments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

to true

```
 config.serve_static_assets = true
```

worked and really worked.

But I do not do that, because another JavaScripts works and that way is not recommended.

So, I tested another way, I copied all content in datatables.js and cut directly in my view.

The firts line are the firsts line of datatables.js.

```
<script type="text/javascripts">

 (function(i,zap,p){i.fn.dataTableSettings=[]; var D=i.fn.dataTablesSettings;i.fn...


$("#ranking").dataTable({
sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
iDisplayLength: 20,
bFilter: true,
aLengthMenu: false,
bLengthChange: false,
bAutoWidth: false,
/* fixa os valores da primeira coluna (index) */
fnDrawCallback: function ( oSettings ) {
/* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */
  if ( oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered ){
    for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ){
        $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr ).html( i+1 );
    }
  }
},
aoColumnDefs: [
    { bSortable: false, aTargets: [ 0 ] },
  { aTargets: [ 14 ], bVisible: false }
],
aaSorting: [[ 13, 'desc' ]],
oLanguage: {
  sUrl: "/javascripts/i18n/data_tables_lang.json"
}
});
</script>
```

And again, did not works in production.

I wanna know what does not work in production, well, I copied the code, I'm not using anyother gem like Jammit.

Why does not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My group uses datatables regularly with no problem. Put the dataTables.js file in your vendor/assets/javascripts folder and set `config.serve_static_assets = false`

I'd also be interested in seeing your production.rb config file as this setting may not be the only one causing problems.

Regarding the `config.serve_static_asset` setting, here's what I found in [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> config.serve_static_assets configures Rails itself to serve static assets. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned off as the server software (e.g. Nginx or Apache) used to run the application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default setting set this to true when running **(absolutely not recommended!)** or testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won't be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.